# None model related field as SlugRelatedField to Serializer

Tags: django

I've added a view to create a new user, this takes a username, password, email and a slug field to link to a permission.

```
{
    "username" : "TestUsername",
    "email" : "TestUsername@outlook.com",
    "password" : "Password01",
    "group" : "partial-permission"
}
```

The view for this request is;

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=CompanyGroup.objects.all(), slug_field='slug_field')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['company', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'token', 'group']
        read_only_fields = ['token']
        write_only_fields = ('password',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

I'm trying to use the SlugRelatedField to link automatically to the Group passed in the slug field and pass this onto my create_user method in my model.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).active_and_not_deleted()

    def create_user(self, username, email, password, group=None, company=None):
        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email), company=company)
        user.set_password(password)

        return user
```

When doing this I'm getting the exception:

```
AttributeError at /users/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `group` on serializer `CreateUserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'group'.
```

I understand that this exception explains exactly what my problem is, but I'm trying to avoid having it on the User object and manually looking up the Group from the objects.

Edit:

Models as request;

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # Date the User was created
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Date the User info was last updated
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # Date the User last logged into the app
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # The company which this user is associated with.
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    # Indicates whether this user has been deleted or not
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def token(self):
        return self._generate_jwt_token()

    def _generate_jwt_token(self):
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)

        token = jwt.encode({
            'id': self.pk,
            'exp': int(dt.strftime('%s'))
        }, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

        return token.decode('utf-8')
```

And group;

```
class CompanyGroup(Group):
    slug_field = models.SlugField()

    objects = GroupManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: can you share your models please?

Comment: @ruddra Updated to show them.

Comment: is there any relation between companygroup and user?

Comment: Not a direct association (as I believe I'm still learning django). In my manager create_user I intend to have something along the lines of; `if not group: group = CompanyGroup.objects.get(name='Default Group')  user.groups.add(group) elif group:  user.groups.add(group)` (sorry for formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I think there needs to have a ManyToMany Relation between `User` and `GroupCompany`(as far as I understood from comments). Because as per [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

> `SlugRelatedField` may be used to represent the target of the relationship using a field on the target.

So, you can add it like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # rest of the fields
    group = models.ManyToManyField(GroupCompany)
```

Need to make sure, `slug_field` is unique in `GroupCompany`:

```
slug_field = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Also, you need to change the `create_user` model manager method as well:

```
def create_user(self, username, email, password, company=None):
    user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email), company=company)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

And update the serializer as well:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=CompanyGroup.objects.all(), slug_field='slug_field', many=True)  # added many True

    def create(self, validated_data):
        group = validated_data.pop('group')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        user.group.add(group)
        return user
```

#### Update

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_group = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)  # added many True

    def create(self, validated_data):
        group = validated_data.pop('company_group')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        group, _ = CompanyGroup.objects.create(slug_field=company_group)
        user.group.add(group)
        return user
```

Comment: Having the many too many relationship means that the request must now contain a list of permissions.  With the code you provided (changed `user.group.add(group)'  to 
 'user.groups.add(group)'  along with not defining the member on the model. I get this error now; `{
    "group": [
        "Expected a list of items but got type \"str\"."
    ]
}` edit: sorry for the formatting not quite sure how to format this in comments.

Comment: @DanielSims as far as I understand, when reading `SlugRelatedField` will return a list, and while writing it will accept a list. Maybe its not what you want. I have updated my answer. Please see the update section, where i take a string field to accept string and store it in DB. Hope it helps